# How to add an item multiple times in a ListViewActivity from another ListViewActivity

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

This is my Original ListView Class where I select an item from the list but I want to select the same item 4 times, then in another activity it should add the item 4 times. I can just add it one time in another activity. I have used sharedpreferences for adding. Can anyone help me with how I can store the value for 4 times?any tips would be appreciated :((( Thanks

//This is the class where I select the item

```
public class Alcohol extends Activity {
private List<Alcohols> alcohol = new ArrayList<Alcohols>();

String wine;
    String beer;
SharedPreferences someData;
public static String filename = "MySharedString";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alcohol);
    someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    AlcoholList();
    AlcohollistView();
    registerClickCallBack();
}

private void registerClickCallBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AlcoholListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                wine = "wine";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor0 = someData.edit();
                editor0.putString("sharedString4", wine);
                editor0.commit();
                                    otherActivity("list");
                break;

            case 1:
                    beer = "beer";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = someData.edit();
                editor1.putString("sharedString5", beer);
                editor1.commit();
                                    otherActivity("list");
                break;
            }
});

}

private void AlcohollistView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<Alcohol> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AlcoholListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pilstyper> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(Alcohol.this, R.layout.list_item_view, alcohol);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_item_view, parent, false);
        }

        Alcohol alcohol = alcohol.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.wine);
        imageView.setImageResource(alcohol.getIkonId());

        // Text
        TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_wine);
        text.setText(alcohol.getText());

        return itemView;
    }
}

private void AlcoholList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    alcohol.add(new Alcohol("Wine", R.drawable.wine));
    alcohol.add(new Alcohol("Beer", R.drawable.beer));
}

public void otherActivity(String a) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    if (a.equals("list")) {
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), list.class);
    }
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
}
```

Here is the another listview class where I want to add an item 4 times if I have selected it four times in the previous class. I can only add one time ://

```
 public class list extends Activity {
private List<Alcohol> alcohol = new ArrayList<Alcohol>();
ArrayAdapter<Alcohol> adapter;
SharedPreferences someData;
public static String filename = "MySharedString";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);
     someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
      String wine = someData.getString("sharedString4", "ooo");
               String beer = someData.getString("sharedString5", "ooo");
      if(wine.equals("wine")){
          alcohol.add(new Alcohol("Wine", R.drawable.wine));

      }else if(wine.equals("wine")){
          alcohol.add(new Alcohol("Beer", R.drawable.beer));

      } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In side onItemClick() just store value which you want to pass to other activity in array list. Like list.add() and then move to other activity with one submit kind of common button. May can put after your list view. And pass that list with intent.

Comment: then it will add the value as many times as the item gets selected?

Answer (score 0):

If it's like adding to cart type, than save each selection to a table or to a object which will be accessible by your previous activity and load it onResume or onStart.